# Alternativa a FosUserBundle con Symfony5

Tags: symfony

estoy comenzando un proyecto pero desgraciadamente me comenzó el proyecto con Symfony 5 y el bundle FosUserBundle no tiene soporte para Symfony5, existe alguna alternativa para esto slds.

PD: También lo estoy utilizando con Easyadmin

Answer (score 3):

OSUserBundle no está recomendado:

https://jolicode.com/blog/do-not-use-fosuserbundle

Te recomiendo que utilices la propia que te da symfony con el `maker bundle`
Aquí tienes unos tutoriales oficiales de symfony de como hacerlo:

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-security/make-user

Si no entiendes el inglés hablado, debajo de cada capítulo hay una transcripción a texto que puedes traducir concualquier traductor, aunque te recomiendo `deepl` que es el que más fiel es y mejor traduce.

En realidad es facil.

empiezas creando una clase `User`o `Usuario` con el comando `php bib/console make:user`
Te preguntará una serie de cosas, es bastante intuitivo.

Una vez tienes la clase `User` creada le puedes añadir propiedades con el comando `php bin/console make:entity` (en el caso de que tus usuarios se guarden en una base de datos a la que tengas acceso) cuando te pregunte el nombre de la entidad le pones `User`, de esa manera reconocerá que la tienes creada y te preguntara que campos quieres añadirle.

Una vez tengas la clase y la entidad de usuario creada, es tan facil como usar el comando `php bin/console make:auth` para crear el login.

el comando del `bin/console` se puede usar de diferentes maneras

Si estás en Windows, desde la carpeta del proyecto tienes que usar `php bin\console [comando]`
Si lo usas desde un linux o un mac y tienes instalado php, sería sin el php delante y con las barras `/` hacia este lado `bin/console [comando]`